# Construct a button to start a routine

Tags: button, gui-construction

When executing `Button ["Print" Print[1]]` you get a button that, if pressed, prints to the screen `1`. What I would like to have is button that performs a set of operations. As a minimal example -- pressing the `Button ["Plot", Plot[x^3, {x,-1,1}]` -- you get this plot. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
doStuff := Module[{}, (* do stuff *)];
Button["Do stuff", doStuff]
```

Here you can put whatever you want in `doStuff`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I write for example ... `doStuff := Module[{}, Print[x^3, {x,-1,1}]]; Button["Do stuff", doStuff]` ... then clicking on the button I see no graphic. :(

Comment: You mean `Plot[x^3, {x,-1,1}]` I assume. Just `Print` it: `doStuff := Module[{}, Print[Plot[x^3, {x,-1,1}]]]` works fine for me.